# Form with DateField: how to check for has_changed()

Tags: django, django-forms

Django 1.10.

Experimenting with forms for learning.

```
The problem is that I can't manage to make form.has_changed() become a False.
```

That is form.has_changed() is always True. The suspicion is that the reason is in DateField. Because pub_date = forms.CharField()  gives expected False result.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.has_changed

Could you give me a kick here:

> 1) Is it because of DateField?
>   2) If so, why it is like that? The
>   produced forms in experiments are identical as far as I can see.  3)
>   3) How to cope?

**Code:**

```
class PubDateForm(forms.Form):  
    pub_date = forms.DateField() 

pub_date_data = {'pub_date': '2015-01-01'}



form = PubDateForm(
                        pub_date_data, 
                        initial=pub_date_data
                       )
has_changed = form.has_changed()
```

**Experiments:**

```
pub_date_data = {'pub_date': '2015-01-01'}
form = PubDateForm(pub_date_data
#                , initial=pub_date_data
                       )
has_changed = form.has_changed()

PubDateForm: <tr><th><label for="id_pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input id="id_pub_date" name="pub_date" type="text" value="2015-01-01" required /></td></tr>


pub_date_data = {'pub_date': '2015-01-01'}
form = PubDateForm(
# pub_date_data, 
                        initial=pub_date_data
                       )

PubDateForm: <tr><th><label for="id_pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input id="id_pub_date" name="pub_date" type="text" value="2015-01-01" required /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `date` object in the initial data instead of a string

```
 pub_date_data = {'pub_date': date(2015, 1, 1)}
```

Note that the important thing is for the `initial` value to be a date. If you provide the form data as a string as in the example below, then `form.has_changed()` will return `False`.

```
form = PubDateForm(data={'pub_date': '2015-01-01'},
                   initial={'pub_date': date(2015, 1, 1)}
                   )
```